# how can I determine the decimal value of a 32bit word containing 4 hexadecimal values?

Tags: endianness, cpu-architecture

Suppose Byte 0 in RAM contains  the value 0x12. Subsequent bytes contain 0x34, 0x45, and 0x78. On a Big-Endian system with a 32-bit word, what’s the decimal value of the word?

I know that for a Big Endian system the order of the word would be 0x78, 0x45, 0x34, 0x12. I converted each value to decimal and got 120, 69, 52, 18. I want to know, in order to get the decimal value of the word, do I add all these values together (120 + 69 + 52 + 18), or do I interpret them as digits in a decimal number (120695218)?

Answer (score 1):

Do you know how to convert a single integer from hex to decimal?  On a big-endian system you have an integer value of `0x12344578` = `... + 5*16^2 + 7*16^1 + 8*16^0`.

---

If you were writing a computer program to print a word as decimal, you'd already have the word as a *binary* integer (hex is a human-readable serialization format for binary, not actually used internally), and you'd do repeated division by 10, using the remainder to as the low digit each time.  (So you generate digits LSD first, in reverse printing order.)

And for a program, endianness wouldn't be an issue.  You'd just do a word load to get the integer value of the word in a register.